# Create Onsen UI elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onsen-ui

Is it possible to create Onsen UI elements dynamically using JavaScript? The official [documentation](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html) says nothing about it.

Comment: Link leads to a 404 page

Comment: There is something in the documentation, indeed: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onscompilefunction

Comment: Thanks i'll check on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var content = document.getElementById("my-content");
    content.innerHTML="<ons-button>Another Button</ons-button>";
    ons.compile(content);
```

with this in you html

```
<div id="my-content"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide any further information to the one previously posted. Anyway, modifying directly the innerHTML con the  `my-content` element, will overwrite the previous content. Moreover, `ons.compile()` method will be called automatically called after appending the element to the DOM

Comment: yeah but you will need to call it if you want to modify the element after appending it to the DOM. it will be called for you once and then you'll need to call it yourself. Correct me if i'am wrong

Comment: It depends on what you are modifying, most part of the attributes can be added and removed dynamically, without any need of calling `ons.compile()`.

Answer (score 7):

You can create dynamically Onsen UUI elements by using `ons._util.createElement()` function. It takes, in input, the HTML code you want to generate. For example:

```
var button = ons._util.createElement("<ons-button></ons-button>");
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

It will create a `ons-button` element, and append it to the body.

*EDIT*

You can also create it in an alternative way:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<ons-button></ons-button>'
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: @Amina to use it you need to use onsen ui latest version from GitHub: [download](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/archive/master.zip). I also updated my answer with an alternative way to do it.